Converting a Span element to a BulletList in a pandoc Lua extension that works for pdf and html
I am trying to take a markdown file that looks like this (this is from a pandoc conversion of a Word document):
# Standard 1.1

## Narrative

::: {custom-style="Body Text"}
Please see artifact 1 ([Artifact 1]{custom-style="Link to Artifact"}). You can also 
add references here as links ([[This is a reference]{custom-style="Hyperlink"}](https://www.website.link/path_to/reffile.pdf)).
:::

## Conclusion

::: {custom-style="Body Text"}
This is my conclusion.
:::

## Sources

[All sources will be automatically listed here. Do not modify this
section.]{custom-style="Sources"}


and convert it to something like this (this would be HTML or PDF as the real output, but this is what the equivalent Markdown would be):
# Standard 1.1

## Narrative

::: {custom-style="Body Text"}
Please see artifact 1 ([Artifact 1]{custom-style="Link to Artifact"}). You can also 
add references here as links ([[This is a reference]{custom-style="Hyperlink"}](https://www.website.link/path_to/reffile.pdf)).
:::

## Conclusion

::: {custom-style="Body Text"}
This is my conclusion.
:::

## Sources

- [Artifact 1](./path_to/Artifact-1.pdf)
- [This is a reference](./path_to/reffile.pdf)


using Quarto (with Pandoc and a Lua extension in the background).
My extension captures the custom-styles Link to Artifact and Hyperlink (which show up in Span elements) and converts them to Link elements (well, it does a lot more, but that is the important part for this question). When that conversion is complete, I save the link in a global table. When I encounter the Sources custom-style, I want to dump out that table as an unordered list (later I will output as either an ordered or unordered list depending on configuration).
This is where I am running into trouble. It seems my table is a Block element and Span is an Inline. How do I convert this table of links into an inline element that will work for both HTML and PDF?
I have tried to convert it using pandoc.utils.blocks_to_inlines, RawInline, RawBlock, etc. Obviously, none of those worked. I can get the list of links in HTML by creating HTML code and just concatenating all the rows into a string and outputting a RawInline. But that does not solve my PDF problem.
While I have figured much of this out, I am still trying to get my head wrapped around how Pandoc and Lua really work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please show your Lua filter (at least the relevant parts)

Without seeing your filter I guess that one approach is to have a styled Block instead of a styled Inline in your markdown document.

In your Lua filter filter.lua use somehting like the following:
local links = {}

Link = function(link)
    table.insert(links, pandoc.Plain(link))
end

Pandoc = function(elem)
    return elem:walk{
        Block = function(s)
            if pandoc.utils.stringify(s) == "YOURSOURCES" then
                return {pandoc.BulletList(links)}
            end
        end
    }
end

with this markdown document input.md
([Link 1](http://www.somedomain.org))

([Link 2](http://www.anotherdomain.org))

[YOURSOURCES]{custom-style="Sources"}

and the following pandoc commmand
pandoc input.md -f markdown -t markdown --lua-filter filter.lua

You get this output:
([Link 1](http://www.somedomain.org))

([Link 2](http://www.anotherdomain.org))

- [Link 1](http://www.somedomain.org)
- [Link 2](http://www.anotherdomain.org)

